# nginx giving 403 if directory present

Tags: angularjs, nginx, server

I have the following configuration that should be working but i still get a 403 if the directory is present in the url path.

Eg: domainname.com/users

If users directory is present i get 403 instead of it loading the index.html.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server_name www.domainname.com;
    return 301 https://www.domainname.com$request_uri;
    root /usr/share/nginx/dist/;
    index  index.html;

    location / {
      autoindex off;
      try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }


    # these settings are from https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/h5bp/location/expires.conf
    # feel free to change as much as you like
    # cache.appcache, your document html and data
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      access_log logs/static.log;
    }

    # Feed
    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
      expires 1h;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the user that runs nginx access the root directory of domainname.com with the current permissions? Same question for the /users/ folder inside the root directory and any files in there also.

Comment: Yes the user that runs nginx can access the root and /users directory of domainname.com with current permissions and everything loads fine, the only problem is when the directory name clashes with the route entered.

Comment: ..and you're not dealing with symbolic links right?

Comment: no i do not have any symbolic links

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify `$url/` in `try_files` to test for the presence of a directory when the trailing `/` is missing:

```
try_files $uri $url/ /index.html =404;
```

This should honour your `index` directive when there is a matching directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i had $uri/ in '/etc/nginx/sites-available/default', just needed to remove this.